# Parse JSON with random atribibute names on Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, webservice-client

I'm working on Angular 6 application that consumes a JSON that has some fixed attributes on a map array (start, end, optional) and others that can exists or not depending from a previous request, note that its names vary also, and I don't have control over them, but they always will be numeric. My doubt is how to parse those variable fields.

```
"speed": 122,
"name":"abc",
"data": [{
    "start":123,
    "end": 456,
    "optional": false,
    "AA": 12.3,
    "S3D": 16.4
 },{
    "start":343,
    "end": 446,
    "optional": false,
    "AA": 13.3,
    "S3D": 14.4
 }]
```

Data.ts

```
export class Data {
   start: number;
   end: number;
   optional: boolean;
}
```

Service.ts

```
getData(): Observable<Data> {
   return this.http.get<Data>(this.endPoint);
}
```

Comment: Those extra fields will be returned by getData() function. What do you mean exactly mean by parse?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what is expected. But check if this is what you are looking for

```
getData(): Observable<Data> {
   return this.http.get(this.endPoint);
}



getData().subscribe(data => {
   for (let key in data) {
      // check if this the keys your looking at 
      // if yes, then start building your data structures manually here

   }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Vivek Kumar, thanks for your answer. But I have many other parent fields. I'll edit my question to reflect the complete scenario.

Comment: Your Data will have the mandatory + extra fields. But if yiu try to use it with dot notation the ts comoiler will give error, so you acn use [] syntax for accessing the dynamic property.

Comment: If you share the error which you are getting can help me understanding your tought and helping you out.

Comment: Hi Vivek, the extra fields are beeing ignored. I'm not receiving an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know all the properties the service will response you could make your interface with that optional properties with "?:" , for example

```
export interface Data {
  start: number;
  end: number;
  optional: boolean;
  optionalProperty?: string;
  optionalProperty2?: number;

 }
```

At this way you don't need to worry about the properties will receive from the service because typescript will map which are coming

I hope this is what you are looking for